# Indentation after linebreak in table

Tags: tabularx

I have a table which looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, two entries are very long and take several lines. How do I indent them?

This is the source code:

```
\begin{tabularx}{.91\textwidth}{l X}
  \toprule
  $\gamma_1$ & \tabitem Unix timestamp\\
             & \tabitem New state $\zeta'$\\
             & \tabitem $\alpha$'s signature $\sigma_\alpha(H(\zeta'))$ of the hash of $\zeta'$\\
  \hline
  $\gamma_2$ & \tabitem $\sigma_i(H(\zeta'))$\\
  \hline
             & \tabitem $A \coloneqq (\sigma_1(H(\zeta')), ..., \sigma_k(H(\zeta')))$\\
  $\gamma_3$ & \tabitem List $C$ of Commitment Transactions. $\forall c_i \in C :$ [$c_i$ sends $\zeta_i$ to a Revocable Sequence Maturity Contract for $m_i$ and $\zeta_j$ to $m_j$ for all $j \not = i, j \in [1..k]$.]\\
  \hline
  $\gamma_{4;i}$ & \tabitem $(\sigma_i(c_1), ..., \sigma_i(c_{i-1}), \text{null}, \sigma_i(c_{i+1}), ..., \sigma_i(c_k))$ [The sequence contains a dummy element because members must not share their signatures for their own respective $c_i$. Defining the sequence this way rather than merely skipping $\sigma_i(c_i)$ has the advantage of there not being a shift by -1 in the indices after $i$.]\\
             & \tabitem Breach Remedy Transaction (Revocation Transaction) $\text{BR}_i$ signed by $m_i$\\
  \hline
  $\gamma_5$ & \tabitem ($\gamma_{4;1},...,\gamma_{4;k}$)\\
  \hline
  $\gamma_{6;i}$ & \tabitem $(\sigma_i(\text{BR}_1), ..., \sigma_i(\text{BR}_k))$\\
  \hline
  $\gamma_7$ & \tabitem ($\gamma_{6;1},...,\gamma_{6;k}$)\\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
```

PS: If you know of a better way of presenting this information, please let me know in the comments.

Comment: How  do you define `\tabitem`? This is not a standard LaTeX command.

Comment: @Bernard It occurs many times on this SE site with varying definitions. I happened to copy this definition to the document this question is about: `\newcommand\tabitem{\makebox[1em][r]{\textbullet~}}`

Comment: OK, but you should post a full, compilable code, to spare  those who want to help the hassle to find how it is defined, complete the code with the necessary packages and so on.

Comment: @Bernard Yeah, you're right. I'm sorry and will post my questions including compilable code in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd like to suggest that you define a custom list -- called `mylist` below -- using the machinery of the `enumitem` package. I'd also like to suggest that you make use of the full width of the textblock and not employ any whitespace padding at the left- and right-hand edges of the `tabularx` environment. To typeset typographic ellipses, write `\dots` (not `...`).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs,mathtools}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{mylist}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[mylist]{label=\textbullet,
                 nosep, wide, leftmargin=*,
                 before=\vspace{-0.57\baselineskip},
                 after =\vspace{-0.85\baselineskip}}
\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{1\textwidth}{@{}l X@{}} % "@{}": no whitespace padding
\toprule
$\gamma_1$ & 
  \begin{mylist}
  \item Unix timestamp
  \item New state $\zeta'$
  \item $\alpha$'s signature $\sigma_\alpha(H(\zeta'))$ of the hash of $\zeta'$
  \end{mylist}\\
\addlinespace
  $\gamma_2$ & \textbullet\ $\sigma_i(H(\zeta'))$\\
\addlinespace
$\gamma_3$ & 
  \begin{mylist}
  \item $A \coloneqq (\sigma_1(H(\zeta')), \dots, \sigma_k(H(\zeta')))$
  \item List $C$ of Commitment Transactions. $\forall c_i \in C :$ [$c_i$ sends $\zeta_i$ to a Revocable Sequence Maturity Contract for $m_i$ and $\zeta_j$ to $m_j$ for all $j\ne i$, $j\in [1\dots k]$.]
  \end{mylist}\\
\addlinespace
$\gamma_{4;i}$ & 
  \begin{mylist}
  \item $(\sigma_i(c_1), \dots, \sigma_i(c_{i-1}), \text{null}, \sigma_i(c_{i+1}), \dots, \sigma_i(c_k))$ [The sequence contains a dummy element because members must not share their signatures for their own respective~$c_i$. Defining the sequence this way rather than merely skipping $\sigma_i(c_i)$ has the advantage of there not being a shift by $-1$ in the indices after~$i$.]
  \item Breach Remedy Transaction (Revocation Transaction) $\text{BR}_i$ signed by~$m_i$
  \end{mylist}\\
\addlinespace
$\gamma_5$ & \textbullet\ ($\gamma_{4;1},\dots,\gamma_{4;k}$)\\
\addlinespace
$\gamma_{6;i}$ & \textbullet\ $(\sigma_i(\text{BR}_1), \dots, \sigma_i(\text{BR}_k))$\\
\addlinespace
$\gamma_7$ & \textbullet\ ($\gamma_{6;1},\dots,\gamma_{6;k}$)\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! Regarding the `\dots` thing: I asked a few people which variant they like better when writing that text. I only provided them with screenshots, not with the source code. I gave them 3 options: `\ldots`, `\rdots`, and `...` in different orders and they all picked the `...` variant. One guy actually responded with something like "Use `\dots`." at first but when I asked him to pick from the screenshots, he picked the screenshot where `...` was used.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a variant solution: the first column enters automatically math mode, and the cells in the second column (based on the `X` type), enter and leave an itemize environment with the suitable parameters:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs,mathtools}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\compress}{\@minipagetrue}
\makeatother

\newcolumntype{L}{ >{\arraybackslash\compress\itemize}X<{\enditemize}}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\setlist[itemize]{wide=0pt, leftmargin=*, nosep=0pt, after =\vspace*{-\dimexpr\baselineskip}}
\setlength{\defaultaddspace}{1.5ex}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}>{$}l<{$}L@{}} % "@{}": no whitespace padding
\toprule
\gamma_1 & \item Unix timestamp
  \item New state $\zeta'$
 \item $\alpha$'s signature $\sigma_\alpha(H(\zeta'))$ of the hash of $\zeta'$ \\
\addlinespace
 \gamma_2 & \item $\sigma_i(H(\zeta'))$ \\%
\addlinespace
\gamma_3 & \item $A \coloneqq (\sigma_1(H(\zeta')), \dots, \sigma_k(H(\zeta')))$
\item List $C$ of Commitment Transactions. $\forall c_i \in C :$ [$c_i$ sends $\zeta_i$ to a Revocable Sequence Maturity Contract for $m_i$ and $\zeta_j$ to $m_j$ for all $j\ne i$, $j\in [1\dots k]$.] \\
\addlinespace
\gamma_{4;i} & \item $(\sigma_i(c_1), \dots, \sigma_i(c_{i-1}), \text{null}, \sigma_i(c_{i+1}), \dots, \sigma_i(c_k))$ [The sequence contains a dummy element because members must not share their signatures for their own respective~$c_i$. Defining the sequence this way rather than merely skipping $\sigma_i(c_i)$ has the advantage of there not being a shift by $-1$ in the indices after~$i$.]
\item Breach Remedy Transaction (Revocation Transaction) $\text{BR}_i$ signed by~$m_i$ \\%
\addlinespace
\gamma_5 & \item ($\gamma_{4;1},\dots,\gamma_{4;k}$) \\%
\addlinespace
\gamma_{6;i} & \item $(\sigma_i(\text{BR}_1), \dots, \sigma_i(\text{BR}_k))$ \\%
\addlinespace
\gamma_7 & \item ($\gamma_{6;1},\dots,\gamma_{6;k}$)\\%
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a list environment for the lists in the right column? You might have to dig a bit to get the spacing correct, but 'X' columns are basically 'p' columns, which means that list environments work in them.

If, for one reason or another, you cannot do that, you could introduce an extra column that holds the '\tabitem's, that will ensure the indentation of the long texts, e.g. :

```
\begin{tabularx}{.91\textwidth}{l r X}
  \toprule
$\gamma_1$ & \tabitem & Unix timestamp\\
             & \tabitem & New state $\zeta'$\\
             & \tabitem & $\alpha$'s signature $\sigma_\alpha(H(\zeta'))$ of the hash of $\zeta'$\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
```

A third option would be the use of the "@" parameter in the column definition:

```
\begin{tabularx}{.91\textwidth}{l @{~\tabitem~}X}
```

Replace the '~' chars by the spacing commands of your liking (@ suppresses the inter-column space)